# Execute a step only once before the whole story

Tags: bdd, jbehave

For instance I need to truncate a database table before running all the scenarios from 1 story:

- `Lifecycle: Before: Given:` will unfortunately run before each scenario
- I don't want to create another story with only that one `Given` to truncate the database and import it with `GivenStories:`, it seems sloppy

Is there another way to execute a step only 1 time before the whole story, declared in the story itself?

Answer (score -1):

You could have database prep contain the story and do it's thing then play the story, this lets you clean up when the story loop terminates. Alternatively you can have a story method that loops (recursively?) and check an external variable...

```
global externalBool = True
storyTime():
    If(externalBool):
         externalBool = false
         #Do Something once 
    #some Stuff happens here
    storyTime()
```

or

```
StoryRecord():
    DbPrep()
    Stories()
    DbClose()
```

Goto isn't a thing in python.